# Add function calls to functions from button

Tags: vb.net, forms, function

I had no idea how to title this post, so for that I apologize.  I'm just going to go for it:

I have `form1` which runs has five main `checkboxes` on it and a `button`.  For each `checkbox` selected when the `button` is pressed, a function runs that calls a list of functions which copies files, blah blah blah.  The problem is that I cannot automate every type of file that gets copied.

So, I created `form2` which has a series of `checkboxes` on it, each one associated with a function.  For each check box on `form 2`, I want a function to be added to the function call list that gets executed on `form1`.

I only want `form2` to be displayed once, and each box that is checked needs to add a function call to the respective `form1` `checkbox` function lists that are checked.

This is difficult to explain, so I'll try to do it with some generic dummy code:

`Form1` Code:

```
If Checkbox1.Checked Then
    Function1()
    Function2()
    Function3()
    'Run functionA or functionB from form2 depending on which boxes are checked
End If
If Checkbox2.Checked Then
    Function1()
    Function2()
    Function3()
    'Run FunctionA or FunctionB from form2 depending on which boxes are checked
End If

Form2 Code:
    Public Sub FunctionA()
        If FunctionA.Checked Then
             'do stuff
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub FunctionB()
        If FunctionB.Checked Then
             'do stuff
        End If
    End Sub
```

I call `Form2.Showdialog()` right after the button click on `Form1` before any code is actually run from `FormA`.  I only want to call `Form2` once and have the program "remember" what was selected for each function selected in `FormA`.  Does any of this make sense??

Comment: You should look into delegates. A delegate is an object that refers to a method. Delegates can be passed around like any other object. That means that you can create a delegate for each method and then add them to a list based on the `CheckBoxes`. When you're done, you just loop through that list and invoke each delegate to execute the method is refers to. In your case, if each method is a `Sub` with no parameters then you should use the `Action` delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simply call the functions in From2 from Form1 based on what has been checked?

```vb
Form1 Code:  
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
    If Checkbox1.Checked Then
        Function1()
        Function2()
        Function3()
        RunSelectedChecks() 'Execute selected Form 2 functions
    End If
    If Checkbox2.Checked Then
        Function1()
        Function2()
        Function3()
        RunSelectedChecks()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RunSelectedChecks() 
    If Form2.Checkbox1.Checked Then Form2.FunctionA()
    If Form2.Checkbox2.Checked Then Form2.FunctionB()
End Sub
```

Comment: Something close to this might work, but can you dynamically create a function to run other functions based on the boxes checked?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamically create a function to run other functions". The fact that box1 is linked to a random function means you need to specify that the function it's linked to. The only way that the function could be found dynamically would be if you named the functions in a way that identifies which check box they relate to and then use reflection to find the function for each box selected. Alternatively you can look into  jmcilhinney's suggestion, however that's still not "dynamic". Also not sure why u need dynamic